# Entity framework relation mapping is not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

print("Hello World !");

I'm a beginner into the .NET world, i'm trying to use entity framework but i have a problem, my relations entities are not loaded, i followed the microsoft documentation but.

Here are my models :

```
[Table("Path")]
public class Path
{
    [Key]
    public int PathId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float LocationX { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float LocationY { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string QrCode { get; set; }
    public List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
}

[Table("Mark")]
public class Mark
{
    [Key]
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int PathForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PathForeignKey")]
    public Path Path { get; set; }
}

[Table("Image")]
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PathForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PathForeignKey")]
    public Path Path { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

For me, everything is ok, i even have the correct entries into my database :
[database entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHFtp.png)

But my relation dont load when i'm reading database into my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Path> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Paths.ToList();
}
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqE9b.png)

I'm sorry, i guess it is probably a stupid beginner error but i dont see what i did wrong. I tried with various database system, with virtual or not ...

Answer (score 3):

Mark your navigation properties as `virtual`. For example:

```
[Table("Mark")]
public class Mark
{
    [Key]
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int PathForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PathForeignKey")]
    public virtual Path Path { get; set; }  //Added virtual keyword
}
```

and a second way to load navigation properties is to use `Include` while fetching data:

```
return _context.Marks.Include(x => x.Path).ToList();
```

Comment: Lazy loading is not available in net core ;) That said, the second aproach is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I am eagerly waiting for lazy-loading feature :)
BTW, he said that he is using Entity Framework, not Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, lets hope that the lazy loading will be available soon :-)